# Silverlight Async Timeout Error

Tags: silverlight, asynchronous, wcf

Calling through to my Silverlight Enabled WCF-Service in my silverlight application, occasionally users get timeouts. Whats the easiest way to boost the time allowed by the service client for a response?

The exact exception thrown is: System.TimeoutException: [HttpRequestTimedOutWithoutDetail]

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Ammount of time connection can be open: [BasicHttpBinding.OpenTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.opentimeout.aspx) property
- Time that a connection can remain inactive, during which no application messages are received, before it is dropped: [BasicHttpBinding.ReceiveTimout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout.aspx) property

This can be set in the  node of the ServiceReference.ClientConfig file in the silverlight app.

Comment: Default values and example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer here did not work for me. Instead I had to cast the base channel into an IContextChannel, and set the OperationTimeout on that.

To do that, I had to create a new file with a partial class, that matched the name of the ServiceReference.  In my case the I had a PrintReportsService.  Code is below.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace RecipeManager.PrintReportsService 
{
    public partial class PrintReportsClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<RecipeManager.PrintReportsService.PrintReports>, RecipeManager.PrintReportsService.PrintReports 
    {
        public void SetOperationTimeout(TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            ((System.ServiceModel.IContextChannel)base.Channel).OperationTimeout = timeout;
        }


    }
}
```

Then when I create the client, I do the following:

```
        PrintReportsService.PrintReportsClient client = new RecipeManager.PrintReportsService.PrintReportsClient();
        client.SetOperationTimeout(new TimeSpan(0, 4, 0));
```

That did it for me!  More info is available [here](http://final-proj.blogspot.com/2009/09/wcf-timeouts.html), but the code snippet in this post doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

This can be set, but there is an upper limit that is defined by the underlying HTTP library (I think its five minutes). Note that using a higher value will fall back to what the upper limit is. Also, be aware that you may need to configure the timeout on the server as well.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by enabling compatibility mode in IE

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the timeout, I think you should implement a timer-based callback to the server from the Silverlight application so that the session doesn't expire. This would eliminate the overhead of longer timeouts for all of your application.