# Timeouts in Silverlight Sockets

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets, timeout

I'm using [`Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)s in my Silverlight application to stream data from a server to a client.

However, I'm not quite sure how timeouts are handled in a Silverlight [`Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).
In the documentation, I cannot see anything like [`ReceiveTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout.aspx) for Silverlight.

- Are user-defined timeouts possible? How can I set them? How can I get notifications when a send / receive operation times out?
- Are there default timeouts? How big are they?
- If there are no timeouts: what's the easiest method to implement these timeouts manually?

Comment: Have you come to some conclusion about it?

Comment: Maybe this should be a comment. Don't the answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331297/silverlight-async-timeout-error) apply to the Socket class as well?

Comment: @Simeon: Nope, because I'm talking about raw sockets.

Comment: are we talking about client socket or server socket. I assume Client. Client framework can not have access to system objects. It is OS's kernel privilege to set up socket pools and manage them. Silverlight can not have such API. Furthermore: there can be a situation when the number of sockets is exosted. In this case OS would not be able to open a socket right away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I couldn't find any nice solution, I solved the problem manually by creating a `System.Threading.Timer` with code similar to the following:

```
System.Threading.Timer t;
bool timeout;

[...]

// Initialization
t = new Timer((s) => {
    lock (this) {
        timeout = true;
        Disconnected();
    }
});

[...]

// Before each asynchronous socket operation
t.Change(10000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

[...]

// In the callback of the asynchronous socket operations
lock (this) {
    t.Change(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    if (!timeout) {
        // Perform work
    }
}
```

This handles also cases where a timeout occurs which is produced by simple lag, and lets the callback return immediately if the operation took too much time.

Answer (score 5):

I've checked the Socket class in Reflector and there's not a single relevant setsockopt call that deals with timeouts - except in the Dispose method. Looks like Silverlight simply relies on the default timeout of the WinSock API.

The Socket class also contains a "SetSocketOption" method which is private that you might be able to call via reflection - though it is very likely that you will run into a security exception.

Comment: +1 Silverlight will indeed throw `MethodInvocationException` if you attempt to invoke non-public methods of any assembly, system or otherwise.

Comment: @RickSladkey: Or an AccessViolationException.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue for my project [sharpLightFtp](https://github.com/dittodhole/sharpLightFtp) like:

Created a [class](https://github.com/dittodhole/sharpLightFtp/blob/master/sharpLightFtp/SocketAsyncEventArgsUserToken.cs) which is injected in the [`UserToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.usertoken%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)-property of an instance of [System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and has an [System.Threading.AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.AutoResetEvent%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), which is used to receive a signal after [`ConnectAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.connectasync%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), [`ReceiveAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receiveasync%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [`SendAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendasync%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) with a timeout (like [here](https://github.com/dittodhole/sharpLightFtp/blob/baf231d30857d4f01c967e4d9869de77644b5df0/sharpLightFtp/Extensions/ComplexSocketExtensions.cs): line 22 for getting a custom enhanced `SocketAsyncEventArgs`-instance, line 270 for creating and enhancing the `SocketEventArgs`-instance, line 286 for sending the signal and line 30 for waiting)