# Request timeout Error in Silverlight after leaving applicaition idle for some time

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I prepared an application in Silver Light. When I leave the application for some time(max 2 min) then click on any save button will give an error request timeout error.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Ammount of time connection can be open: [BasicHttpBinding.OpenTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.opentimeout.aspx) property
Time that a connection can remain inactive, during which no application messages are received, before it is dropped: [BasicHttpBinding.ReceiveTimout property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout.aspx)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331297/silverlight-async-timeout-error)